# Find a value for c such that a sequence is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am working on practice problems for an upcoming midterm in my introduction to real analysis course, and there is one practice problem involving sequences that is troubling me.

> Let $s_1 = c$ and define $s_{n+1} = \sqrt(4s_n - 1)$. Determine what values of c will make the sequence $s_n$ monotone increasing or monotone decreasing.

Here's what I thought to try:

> Let the sequence $s_n$ be a constant sequence. That is, $s_n = s_{n+1}$. Then
>   $s_n = \sqrt(4s_n - 1)$, or $s_n^2 = 4s_n - 1$, or $s_n^2 - 4s_n + 1 = 0$. If $s_n = s_1$, then $c^2 - 4c + 1 = 0$. Finding the roots of $c^2 - 4c + 1 = 0$, we get $c = 2 + \sqrt3$ and $c = 2 - \sqrt3$. Thus, if $c = 2 + \sqrt(3)$ or $c = 2 - \sqrt(3)$, then $s_n = s_{n+1} = s_{n+2} = ...$

I also found that

> $s_1 = 2$, $s_{n+1} = \sqrt(4s_n - 1)$

is monotone increasing. Can I then say that:

> If $k \in [2-\sqrt3, 2+\sqrt3]$, then sequence is monotone increasing. If $k \in [1/4, 2-\sqrt3] \cup k \in [2+\sqrt3, \infty)$, then sequence is monotone decreasing.

Or do I have to show something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is definitely not immediately clear why the answer is true.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct but it should be better explained.

Say you want to know when $(s_n)$ is monotone increasing.
Then you have to solve $s_{n+1}>s_n$, that is

$$\sqrt{4s_n-1}>s_n\iff4{s_n}-1>{s_n}^2.$$

Here we have assumed the $s_n$ are all non-negative.
Indeed, if some $s_n$ were less than $1/4$, then $s_{n+1}$ would be ill-defined.
Well, what we have hence is

$${s_n}^2-4s_n+1<0.$$

This looks like your quadratic equation!
Indeed, since the coefficient of the quadratic term is positive, the inequality will be satisfied when $s_n$ lies strictly between the roots of the corresponding equality.
More explicity:

$$2-\sqrt{3}<s_n<2+\sqrt{3}$$

In particular, $s_1=c$ must also satisfy this.

Are we finished?
If we were to be super rigorous, I'd say no.
We'd still have to show that if the inequality above is satisfied, then $s_{n+1}<2+\sqrt{3}$.
This way, we guarantee that it never increases past the mark.
Thankfully, showing this is easy.
We have that:

$$s_{n+1}<2+\sqrt{3}\iff{s_{n+1}}^2<7+4\sqrt{3}\iff4s_n-1<7+4\sqrt{3}\\
\iff4s_n<8+4\sqrt{3}\iff s_n<2+\sqrt{3}.$$

Ah, it's all good then!
Do you think you can use similar reasoning to show the $s_{n+1}<s_n$ case?